# Assigning array values to incremental variables with PHP to insert into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have the following results page from the previous form:

```
<?php
//Get the form results (which has been converted to an associative array) from the $_POST super global
$musicgenres = $_POST['music'];

//Sort the values by rank and keep the key associations.
asort($musicgenres, SORT_NUMERIC );

//Loop over the array in rank order to print out the values.
foreach($musicgenres as $music => $rank)
{
    echo "$music is your $rank choice";
   echo "<br>";
 }
?>
```

Here  is an example of the output (without the bullets):

- Rap is your 1 choice
- Rock is your 2 choice
- Jazz is your 3 choice
- etc....

I'm thinking that putting this into a table will not be easy or clean. How can assign these values to incremental variables?

e.g.

- $musicrank1 = rap
- $musicrank2 = rock
- $musicrank3 = jazz
- etc....

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Dynamically creating an undetermined number of variables looks like a hack.

Comment: make a music_ranks table  and insert rank and music .Then do whatever you want to do. If it is dynamic then update the music_rank table using query.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$i = 0;
//Loop over the array in rank order to print out the values.
foreach($musicgenres as $music => $rank)
{
    ${ "musicrank". ($i) }  =   $music;
    echo "$music is your $rank choice";
   echo "<br>";
   $i++;
 }
```

after foreach you'll have your variables.

Answer (score 2):

Using a table is much easier than creating arbitrary variables. With the table you just have to say `$musicrank[1]` instead of `$musicrank1` and you can iterate over the table if you want to.

As a rule of thumb, if you'd assign each value in the table manually, you should use variables instead. But you are using a loop, so it's a pretty obvious case for tables.

Answer (score 0):

use this script : for add array with comma

```
        `$no = 0;
        foreach($sql2 as $row2)
        {
            $row["store_name"] .= ($no != 0) ? ", " : "";
            $row["store_name"] .= $row2["store_name"];

            $no++;
        }
```